# What are the best resources for learning how to implement Naive Bayes Classifiers in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, data-mining, bayesian

After asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019153/what-type-of-algorithm-would-you-use-to-help-forecast-future-performance-based-on), I've decided to try and implement some Naive Bayes Classifiers using SQL Server Analysis Services.

Can anyone point me to a decent book, website or any other resource on how to implement Naive Bayes Classifiers in SSAS?  Similarly, I would be interested in learning about Decision Trees.

Answer (score 2):

[Data Mining with SQL Server 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470277742) - this book explains what each algorithm does and walks you through how to apply each one. Definitely read it if you're getting into Data Mining.

[SQL Server Data Mining](http://www.sqlserverdatamining.com/ssdm/) - site which gives tutorials, samples, etc.